# Change the name of the radiobutton in the gridview while render

Tags: asp.net

After render group name comes in the name attribute with different name for each radiobutton in the gridview.

I tried to set all the names as same. But when we see the source in the browser it is unique.

How to change the name for all the radiobutton in the gridview as same.

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    base.Render(htw);
    htw.Close();
    string h = sw.ToString();

    RadioButton first = (RadioButton)gvAddOption.Rows[0].Cells[3].FindControl("rblValue");
    string uniqGroupName = first.UniqueID;
    uniqGroupName = uniqGroupName.Replace(first.ID, first.GroupName);


    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvAddOption.Rows)
    {
        RadioButton val = (RadioButton)row.Cells[3].FindControl("rblValue");
        string eachGroupName = val.UniqueID;
        eachGroupName = eachGroupName.Replace(val.ID, val.GroupName);
        //h.Replace("name=\"" + eachGroupName + "\"", "name=\"" + uniqGroupName + "\"");

        h.Replace(eachGroupName, uniqGroupName);

    }

    writer.Write(h);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about using HTML controls instead of .Net ones? This should give you move control over what is rendered.